# How do I remove this window sash to replace the glass pane?

Tags: windows

I have watched a lot of videos on removing the pane and reglazing. It doesn't seem that hard. I'm stuck though on how to remove the sash. I have a video I made which goes over the entire window.

[See the window in a video](https://youtu.be/2jWfSGemEC8)

[image: Is there a way to embed on DIY?]

Comment: @jwillis0720 The vid. focuses on the meeting rail of the sash but the important part is the window frame and the sash channel (is it a split channel or mono-piece); particularly the top corners of the frame (butt glue-weld or screwed together).  Also, a look at the window frame and where it meets the wall could be helpful to see if this is a replacement window insert (which it appears to be).

Comment: BTW, I suspect the frame needs to be removed to remove the sash.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the sash is stuck within the frame.

However, there might be glazing stops that you can gently pry off with a stiff putty knife. (This is hard, btw. Every one I've ever met has been thin and easy to mangle.)

If you get the stops off successfully, you can order a new thermal unit from a specialty place. (While you're there, show them the stops to see if they have new ones.) Install is pretty straightforward, though you'll be happier if you have a couple of suction cup grabbers.

Comment: So appropriate that @Defenestrate would answer a broken window question :)